# symfony 4 - default normalization to snake_case

Tags: symfony, datetime, serialization, snakecasing

trying to get the sf4 serializer component to use snake_case as the default:

```
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer:
        public: true
        arguments: ['@serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory', '@serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case']
        tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

works.

but now **DateTime is being normalized to empty arrays**.
I don't get why, without the config changes, its normalized to a date string, as you would expect.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out, you simply need to enable a name_converter the proper way like this **instead**:

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    # ...
    serializer:
        name_converter: 'serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case'
```

see
https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#enabling-a-name-converter
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40818